# Find last alphanumeric value in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a field that contains usernames in a mysql db
eg:

```
johndoe2
johndoe10
johndoe3
```

If i order by that field `DESC` I get:

```
johndoe3
johndoe2
johndoe10
```

I need to get:

```
johndoe10
johndoe3
johndoe2
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: What character encoding and collation are you currently using?

Comment: Without a control character separating the string from the number, it's extremely difficult to reliably retrieve the numeric value for ordering.  IE: `RIGHT(field, 1)` would return "0" rather than "10"...

Comment: Couldn't you pad those numbers (eg: johndoe2 becomes johndoe02)? Or store them in a different column?

Comment: @NullUserException: Then you have to revisit the padding when you get #'s in the 100's, 1,000's etc.  MySQL has regex support, but it's very limited - there's no regex substring which would've made this short work.

Comment: @OMG Well, just pad to a size you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

This is a giant hack, but I think will work. If your column name is s:

```
order by 
  (replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(s, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', ''),
  length(s) desc,
  s desc
```

First sort by the alphabetic part of the text, to get all the same names together, then by length to get them sorted roughly numerically, then by s.  The last `order by s` works properly now because it's only used to disambiguate between same names with the same number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

If performance isn't a concern, consider writing a [function like this one to remove non-numeric characters](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?118,229993,240768#msg-240768), and then simply including the call in your ORDER BY.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM MyTable
 ORDER BY 
      CAST(strip_alpha(UserName) as int) DESC
```

For a more performant + hassle-free solution, consider extracting the number from the username into a new column. Then you could easily ORDER BY:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE  UserName LIKE 'johndoe%'
 ORDER BY TrailingDigit DESC
```